# WxPython - Resize WxFrame when adding new content?

Tags: python, wxpython

Pretty much exactly as it sounds. I have buttons in a `Wx.Frame` that are created on the fly and I'd like the parent frame to increase in height as I add new buttons. The height is already being acquire from the total number of buttons multiplied by an integer equal the each button's height, but I don't know how to get the frame to change size based on that when new buttons are added.

As a side question the current method I have for updating the buttons creates a nasty flicker and I was wondering if anyone had any ideas for fixing that.

```
import wx
import mmap
import re

class pt:
    with open('note.txt', "r+") as note:
        buf = mmap.mmap(note.fileno(), 0)
        TL = 0
        readline = buf.readline
        while readline():
            TL += 1
        readlist = note.readlines()
    note.closed

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        w, h = wx.GetDisplaySize()
        self.x = w * 0
        self.y = h - bdepth

        self.container = wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title = title, pos = (self.x, self.y), size = (224, bdepth), style = wx.STAY_ON_TOP)


        self.__DoButtons()

        self.Show(True)

    def __DoButtons(self):

        for i, line in enumerate(pt.readlist):

            strip = line.rstrip('\n')
            todo = strip.lstrip('!')

            self.check = re.match('!', strip)
            self.priority = re.search('(\!$)', strip)

            if self.check is None and self.priority is None:
                bullet = wx.Image('bullet.bmp', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP)

                solid = wx.EmptyBitmap(200,64,-1)
                dc = wx.MemoryDC()
                dc.SelectObject(solid)
                solidpen = wx.Pen(wx.Colour(75,75,75),wx.SOLID)
                dc.SetPen(solidpen)
                dc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, 200, 64)
                dc.SetTextForeground(wx.Colour(255, 255, 255))
                dc.DrawBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(bullet, 32), 10, 28)
                dc.DrawText(todo, 30,  24)
                dc.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)

                hover = wx.EmptyBitmap(200,64,-1)
                dc = wx.MemoryDC()
                dc.SelectObject(hover)
                hoverpen = wx.Pen(wx.Colour(100,100,100),wx.SOLID)
                dc.SetPen(hoverpen)
                dc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, 200, 64)
                dc.SetTextForeground(wx.Colour(255, 255, 255))
                dc.DrawBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(bullet, 32), 10, 28)
                dc.DrawText(todo, 30,  24)
                dc.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)

                bmp = solid

            elif self.priority is None:
                checkmark = wx.Image('check.bmp', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP)

                checked = wx.EmptyBitmap(200,64,-1)
                dc = wx.MemoryDC()
                dc.SelectObject(checked)
                checkedpen = wx.Pen(wx.Colour(50,50,50),wx.SOLID)
                dc.SetPen(checkedpen)
                dc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, 200, 50)
                dc.SetTextForeground(wx.Colour(200, 255, 0))
                dc.DrawBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(checkmark, 32), 6, 24)
                dc.DrawText(todo, 30,  24)
                dc.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)

                bmp = checked

            else:
                exclaim = wx.Image('exclaim.bmp', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP)

                important = wx.EmptyBitmap(200,64,-1)
                dc = wx.MemoryDC()
                dc.SelectObject(important)
                importantpen = wx.Pen(wx.Colour(75,75,75),wx.SOLID)
                dc.SetPen(importantpen)
                dc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, 200, 50)
                dc.SetTextForeground(wx.Colour(255, 180, 0))
                dc.DrawBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(exclaim, 32), 6, 24)
                dc.DrawText(todo, 30,  24)
                dc.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)

                importanthover = wx.EmptyBitmap(200,64,-1)
                dc = wx.MemoryDC()
                dc.SelectObject(importanthover)
                importanthoverpen = wx.Pen(wx.Colour(100,100,100),wx.SOLID)
                dc.SetPen(importanthoverpen)
                dc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, 200, 50)
                dc.SetTextForeground(wx.Colour(255, 180, 0))
                dc.DrawBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(exclaim, 32), 6, 24)
                dc.DrawText(todo, 30,  24)
                dc.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)

                bmp = important

            b = wx.BitmapButton(self, i + 800, bmp, (10,  i * 64), (bmp.GetWidth(), bmp.GetHeight()), style = wx.NO_BORDER)


            if self.check is None and self.priority is None:
                b.SetBitmapHover(hover)
            elif self.priority is None:
                b.SetBitmapHover(checked)
            else:
                b.SetBitmapHover(importanthover)

        self.input = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "", (16, pt.TL * 64 + 4), (184, 24))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.OnEnter, self.input)

    def OnClick(self, event):
        button = event.GetEventObject()
        button.None
        print('cheese')

    def OnEnter(self, event):
        value = self.input.GetValue()
        pt.readlist.append('\n' + value)

        self.__DoButtons()

        with open('note.txt', "r+") as note:
            for item in pt.readlist:
                note.write("%s" % item)
        note.closed

bdepth = pt.TL * 64 + 32
app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainWindow(None, "Sample editor")
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there no way automatically resize the frame, but you can manually reset the size of your frame with `SetSize()`

e.g.

```
w, h = self.GetClientSize()
self.SetSize((w, h + height_of_your_new_button))
```

To the get the desired result though with minimum hassle you'll need to use sizers, I don't think theres ever a good reason to use absolute positioning. I would also recommend using a panel, which provides  tab traversal between widgets and cross platform consistency of layout.

---

[Zetcode Sizer Tutorial](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/layout/)

[wxPython Sizer Tutorial](http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxDesigner%20Sizer%20Tutorial)

Comment: I just noticed this ---> `b = wx.BitmapButton(self, i + 800,..` .Your asking for trouble if you dont let wxPython choose `id's`  by using either `-1`, `wx.ID_ANY` or `wx.NEW_ID()` otherwise you could cause  conflicts.

Comment: Thank you. The Zetcode page in particular is very helpful. I changed the IDs to let wxPython choose as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't** double-prefix your methods unless you know what you're doing. This is not directly related to your question, but it'll result in bugs you won't understand later.

See this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python) question and [the python documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) what/why.

Comment: Thank you, actually, anything and everything is helpful right now. I'm very new to this (obviously).